# Can't add message body to PHP without loosing attachment

Tags: php

I have finally pieced together a code that would allow me to send an FDF file from my server to e-mail that didn't reduce my file to a 0kb attachment. Problem is, that I had to get rid of the body of the e-mail to do it.

I want to be able to add an HTML (or plain text) body to the e-mail being sent. Kind of like:

```
<h2>DWR Submittal</h2>
<p>Process the attachment in the system.</p>

STEP 1. Download file
STEP 2. Open with Adobe Acrobat
STEP 3. Verify form data
STEP 4. etc...
STEP 5. etc...
```

Where or how could this be done without compromising the attachment

```
<?php
  $fileatt = './dwrdocuments/dwr.fdf'; // Path to the file
  $fileatt_type = "application/octet-sdiveam"; // File Type
  $fileatt_name = date(mdy_his).'_dwr.fdf'; 
  $email_from = $_POST['From']; // Who the email is from
  $email_subject = 'DWR Submittal'; // The Subject of the email
  $email_txt = $_POST['Comments']; // Message that the email has in it

  $email_to = 'admin@example.com'; // Who the email is to

  $headers = "From: ".$email_from;

  $file = fopen($fileatt,'rb');
  $data = fread($file,filesize($fileatt));
  fclose($file);

  $semi_rand = md5(time());
  $mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x";

  $headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" .
  "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" .
  " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";

  $email_message .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" .
  "--{$mime_boundary}\n" .
  "Content-Type:text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" .
  "Content-divansfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" .
  $email_message . "\n\n";

  $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));

  $email_message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n" .
  "Content-Type: {$fileatt_type};\n" .
  " name=\"{$fileatt_name}\"\n" .
  //"Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" .
  //" filename=\"{$fileatt_name}\"\n" .
  "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" .
  $data . "\n\n" .
  "--{$mime_boundary}--\n";

  $ok = @mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
  header ("Location: ../confirm.html");  
?>
```

Comment: Loose is a different word than lose.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

```
$email_message .= '<h2>DWR Submittal</h2>
<p>Process the attachment in the system.</p>

STEP 1. Download file
STEP 2. Open with Adobe Acrobat
STEP 3. Verify form data
STEP 4. etc...
STEP 5. etc...';
```

Right before:

```
$data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));
```